# webdriverio browser.elementHover is not a function

Tags: webdriver-io

Using `"webdriverio": "^8.16.19"` I'd like to hover over an element in a webdriver.io test using [elementhover](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/chromium/#elementhover):

```
 const InstagramWidgetThumb = await $('app-users-widgets .widgets app-instagram-widget-thumbnail');
 await browser.execute((el) => { el.style.border = '5px solid #00ff22' }, InstagramWidgetThumb);
 await(browser.pause(1000));
 await browser.execute((el) => { el.style.border = 'none' }, InstagramWidgetThumb);
 await(browser.elementHover(InstagramWidgetThumb));
```

This last line produces an error

> browser.elementHover is not a function.

I expected the element `InstagramWidgetThumb` to show the hover state.

If I use:

- `await(browser.elementHover('app-users-widgets .widgets app-instagram-widget-thumbnail'));` or
- `await browser.elementHover('app-users-widgets .widgets app-instagram-widget-thumbnail');`

the same error occurs.

I can't reproduce this error in a dummy project.

The error is not found on Google so I'm stumped.